# Is it possible to inject your own set of variables into a Drone build?

Tags: drone.io

I'm using Drone 0.5. Our build process compiles code to generate an artifact that is deployed to an artifact repository. I need a reference to this artifact for use in later build steps.

Is there a way to pass arbitrary data between build steps? Maybe through environment variables?

Comment: on a side note, we have an eerily similar stack overflow score/badges... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about creating env variables during the build process and persisting them, but the file system is definitely preserved. So you could put whatever data you need into a file for the next step.

Comment: That's for sure. The idea is to not mangle with the workspace and for example dynamically modify the parameters of a plugin during the build process. Given the params of a plugin are all envars.